# Can't delete from SD card, 'Read-only file system'

Tags: mount, sd-card

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

I have an SD card that I use with my camera, and I'm trying to delete photos from it. I was able to move them to the Trash, but when I try to delete any of the files out of the Trash I get `Failed to delete the item from the trash`.

I can navigate to the `.Trash-1000/files` directory on the device, but when I try to `sudo rm` the files, I get `rm: cannot remove ‘IMG_1483.JPG’: Read-only file system`.

`mount` gives me this:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/zack/6562-61611 type vfat (ro,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)
```

I tried re-mounting the device using `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/zack/SD -o rw,dmask=0000` and got the same error when I tried to delete the files.

Finally, I have checked the switch on the card itself and confirmed it's in the unlocked position. I tried switching it to locked just in case it was a goofy card and I couldn't delete off of it then either.

What's going on here? How can I get rid of these files?

**Update 1:** I tried a couple other things in response to aventurin's comment. I took a new picture, then tried to `sudo rm` it and that worked. When I went back to `.Trash-1000/files` and tried it again, I was able to delete some files but not others:

```
$ ls
100___12
101___01
102___02    # directories
103___03
...
IMG_1365.JPG
IMG_1374.JPG
IMG_1375.JPG
IMG_1380.JPG
...

$ sudo rm -rvf *.JPG
removed ‘IMG_1365.JPG’
removed ‘IMG_1374.JPG’
removed ‘IMG_1375.JPG’
rm: cannot remove ‘IMG_1380.JPG’: Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove ‘IMG_1381.JPG’: Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove ‘IMG_1383.JPG’: Read-only file system
...
```

...and so on. I did an `ll` right before I deleted those files, and the permissions for all of the .JPG files look exactly the same.

**Update 2:**

```
$ dmesg | grep sdb1
[  714.950034] FAT-fs (sdb1): error, invalid access to FAT (entry 0x6ce0c8c0)
... # a bunch more of those
[ 2192.017345] FAT-fs (sdb1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[ 2192.663466] sdb1: rw=0, want=105540772768, limit=62325760
[ 2192.663470] sdb1: rw=0, want=105540772744, limit=62325760
[ 2192.663499] FAT-fs (sdb1): error, invalid access to FAT (entry 0xad23600b)
[ 2192.663501] FAT-fs (sdb1): Filesystem has been set read-only
[ 2192.663601] FAT-fs (sdb1): error, invalid access to FAT (entry 0x58f3a807)
[ 2271.537913]  sdb: sdb1
[ 2273.782060] FAT-fs (sdb1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[ 2407.374492] FAT-fs (sdb1): error, fat_free_clusters: deleting FAT entry beyond EOF
[ 2407.374496] FAT-fs (sdb1): Filesystem has been set read-only
```

I tried `sudo fsck /dev/sdb1` and got a lot of errors:

```
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
1) Remove dirty bit
2) No action
? 1
...
/.Trash-1000/files/IMG_1483.JPG  and
/.Trash-1000/files/117___09/IMG_1737.JPG
  share clusters.
1) Truncate first to 5439488 bytes
2) Truncate second to 0 bytes
? 1
```

I told it to fix them all, but when I run it again they all show up again.

**Update 3:**

I unmounted the card, and ran `sudo fsck /dev/sdb1 -a`. It ran for about 6 hours and still wasn't finished so I eventually Ctrl-C'd it. It mostly seemed to be renaming files with corruped usernames, and was up to almost 18000 files renamed before I killed it (I've certainly never taken that many photos before...).

I then tried `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/zack/SD -v -o rw` and got this output:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/zack/SD -v -o rw
mount: you didn't specify a filesystem type for /dev/sdb1
       I will try type vfat
/dev/sdb1 on /media/zack/SD type vfat (rw)
```

Despite not having an error, I still cannot delete the files and get the same old "read-only file system" error.

Comment: Does rm as root work? Does rm work for files not in trash?

Comment: @aventurin, sorry, I should have specified that I was using `sudo` for just about everything. I've updated the question with that change, as well as the results of your second suggestion.

Comment: Does dmesg show any errors related to the SD card?

Comment: @aventurin, updated the question again.

Comment: You did not specify what error you got when mounting the device with `-o rw`.  Also, you umounted the device before mounting it again, right?

Comment: @grochmal, I don't think I got an error when mounting. I tried it again and didn't get an error, but still can't delete the files. I'm pretty sure I unmounted before mounting, but it's possible I forgot.

Comment: How did you tell fsck to fix the errors? -a or -r option? If it really tried to fix errors and it did not work, your SD card probably is defect.

Comment: mount has `-v` for verbose, it is a very good debugging tool.  umount and mount again in verbose, if the there is a reason it cannot make the filesystem writable it will tell you.  (and yeah, update the question with that output)

Comment: Some SD cards have an mechanical RW lock. Does yours?

Comment: aventurin and grochmal, I updated the question in response to your suggestions. @Serge, it does have a physical switch, and I have tried it in both positions to make sure. When it's in the locked position I get a warning that it's locked from my camera, but when it's switched to unlocked I don't get that warning. In both cases, I can't delete the files in the trash.

Comment: To verify that the SD card is defective, the next step is checking for bad blocks. As @MayeulC suggested you can use `badblocks` for this. **Be aware that the -w option will erase all data from the device. Be sure that you specify the correct device!** Assuming `/dev/sdb` is your SD card, with `blockdev --getbsz /dev/sdb` you can determine the block size to be passed to `badblocks` -b option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filesystem seems to be corrupted. If you can't let fsck run until the end, I suggest reformating the card with `mkfs.vfat`. But to avoid later corruption, I advise you to check your SD card with `badblocks` first (you can use the destructive `-w` option, but you will need to recreate the partition table afterwards - with `cfdisk`, for instance).
Then, if you have any bad blocks, you can pass them to the mkfs command like so:

```
badblocks -w -o ~/badblocksList /dev/sda
mkfs.vfat -l ~/badblocksList /dev/sda
```

Note: alternatively, you can use `mkfs.vfat -c` to perform a simple bad blocks check when formatting. Please also note that FAT is not a journaling filesystem, and, as such, is quite sensitive to corruption if not properly unmounted. If possible, try to avoid its use on devices you carry around.

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't find any bad blocks. `mkfs.vfat` also returned an error, though I don't remember now what it was. I decided to just use gparted to reformat the card to FAT32, and it seems like everything's working now. Thanks for your help, everyone!

Comment: Your partition table might have been corrupted, then. It might have been possible to generate a new one that matched the existing filesystem, but it is likely that both were corrupt. `gparted` was a good call. `fdisk` or `cfdisk` can do that too, but `gparted` (or `parted`) handles everything from the partition table to formatting partitions.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm: cannot remove '/XXX/.Trash-1000/files/XXX.rtf': Read-only file system
```

Hours ago, on a USB stick, I got the same error as shown above. By googling, I found this webpage. I tried the suggested methods but to no avail. Then I started Windows in VirtualBox. Windows successfully deleted the "**.Trash-1000**" folder and everything inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `hdparm -r0 /dev/sda1` (modify to your device path as appropriate), then ejecting and re-inserting the card worked for me. Simply remounting with the `mount` command didn't.

Got the answer from https://askubuntu.com/a/342448/638715

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue on **xfce-debian** happened.

I remove some files with long name and Persian name from A **fat32** flash memory.
When mount it **thunar** shows them in Trash and ready to restore them, but if I try to restore or just remove them permanently it cant do any things and show **ReadOnly** file system then abort operation.

This steps fix it

- Unmount flash drive

`umount /dev/sdx`

- Use fsck on partiotion

`fsck.vfat /dev/sdx1`

> Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be
> corrupt.

Choose Remove dirty bit

And

> Bad short file name ( ).

Choose Auto-rename

After that accept them with `y`

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same problem. This worked for me:

- Put the SD card in a USB reader
- mount it
- go to its folder in terminal

> `sudo rm -Rf .Trash-1000/`

Comment: This removes your trash. Why on earth would this work?