# How does the kernel decide to make an SD card filesystem read-only?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, sd-card, flash-memory

I understand that low-level NAND flash can effectively wear out and that an SD card controller (residing on the card itself) is responsible for managing the flash and exposing a comparatively simple interface to the host.

Many have reported the case of a filesystem suddenly becoming read-only.

How is a bad flash page detected at the SD card layer? How is this error passed to the filesystem? What is the mechanism by which the kernel detects this and makes the filesystem read-only?

Is the error reported at the SD card layer specific? For example, ECC failed or the page could not be marked as bad? Or is it just: I can't read or write what was requested?

We're having this issue with a root filesystem on an SD card. Sometimes the filesystem becomes read-only. Other times it doesn't but we observe corrupt files. Why weren't the corrupt files detected?

Comment: If a flash memory wears out, you don't get corruption, you get write errors. Corruption indicates that something else is wrong. SD cards are not very reliable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308009/cant-delete-from-sd-card-read-only-file-system